# Unable to change background image on a workdpress website

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I am trying to edit the background image on this website- http://genesisconcretefl.com/ through the admin panel. I checked all options including media library, posts, pages, etc but I am unable to figure out how to change the background image. 
I am not a developer. Can somebody please guide me how to change it?

Comment: The theme you are using which is pretty old, Advising you to use latest template.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am thinking to change the theme and re-design it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be used the Bizstudiolite theme. You can also use the theme option for this:

1. Bizstudiolite Options >> General Settings >> Custom Background >> select color and upload your background image then select no-repeat, top center, fixed in place.
2. Save options.

*some additional options can find here, (If you want Background Gallery Off then go there)

- go to WordPress Backend panel >> Appearance >> Full Width Background
  Gallery >> DISPLAY SETTINGS >>  You cand find background gallery
  options.

Comment: Thank you. I found it the way you explained.